# Keep cookies after redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies, woocommerce

I'm having an issue with woocommerce cookies being unset after a redirect.

Basically the site redirects to a backend site, 'training.', where the user is logged into that system. They are then redirected back to 'www.', where they are logged into WP. This is done in 'header.php'.

The problem I have is that the three woocommerce cookies are unset on returning to 'www.'

```
woocommerce_cart_hash
woocommerce_items_in_cart
wp_woocommerce_session_
```

I've tried setting the `domain` and `path` on the cookie, but it still gets unset.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try starting the domain name with a dot? E.g. `.example.com`?

Comment: @Siguza, I did, but no joy.